# default children route with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue 2.x application and I'm using vue-router to handle the routing.

In some scenario, I have to display directly a children vue. My template is the following:

```
| voice 1 | voice 2 | voice 3 |

    | submenu 1 | submenu 2 | submenu 3 |

|
| content 1
|
```

So basically I have a menu, when you select a menu voice the relative submenu is displayed, when you select a submenu voice the relative content is displayed.

The routeing system follows the menu structure so if you go to `/voice1/submenu1` you should display the `content 1`, if you click to submenu2 then you go to `/voice1/submenu2` and display `content 2` and so on and so forth.

When the user logs in, I don't want to present an empty page, but I want the route to be already populated with default components (in this case `voice 1`, `submenu 1`, `content 1`), but I don't know how to do that. For now I solved the problem adding this in my route interceptor:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) ⇒ {
  const token = store.getToken();

  const tokenIsValid = validateToken(token);
  const routeDoesntNeedAuth = routeWithoutAuth.indexOf(to.fullPath) > -1;

  if (tokenIsValid || routeDoesntNeedAuth) {
    if (to.fullPath === '/') {
      next('/voice1/submenu1');       // <- this line does the trick
    }

    next();
  } else {
    next('/login');
  }
});
```

But I'm sure there's a better way to do this. My route system is the following:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: AppWrapper,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/voice1',
          components: {
            default: PageWrapper,
            subMenu: VoiceFirstSubMenu,
          },
          children: [
            {
              path: 'submenu1',
              components: {
                mainContent: ContentOne,
              },
            },
            {
              path: 'submenu2',
              components: {
                mainContent: ContentTwo,
              },
            },
            {
              path: 'submenu3',
              components: {
                mainContent: ContentThree,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: Login,
    },
  ],
});
```

How can I solve this?

Divine's question is correct, the problem was that I had this line of code that was redirecting all my routes to `/`:

```
this.$router.push('/');
```

In a wrapper component that contains the whole application. Once removed that line everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `redirect` property in the `route config` to redirect any route

whenever `/` route is invoked vuejs will automatically redirect to `/voice1/submenu1`

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/voice1/submenu1', <---- / route will be redirected to /voice1/submenu1
      component: AppWrapper,
      children: [
         ...
      ]
    },
]
```

Comment: the problem now is that if I reload the page from `/voice1/submenu2` is gonna redirect me to `/voice1/submenu1`

Comment: @ste did you test my answer or just saying it without testing?

Comment: @ste i recommend you to test it in your machine and confirm. because redirect property is working fine in mine.

Comment: I can't, it's a proprietary project, and with jsfiddle I can refresh the page with a different route, but that's what happen: basically the redirect catches all the children route during refresh, so if I refresh either  `/voice1/submenu2` or  `/voice1/submenu3` I end up in `voice1/submenu1`